# SQL Server: strange, SELECT INTO cloned a record

Tags: sql, sql-server

With a SQL Server 2005 instance, I write a simple query:

```
SELECT * 
  INTO TABLE_cloned 
  FROM TABLE
```

At the end of the execution, `TABLE_cloned` contains a record twice.

- Original table had a clustered unique primary key index
- Instruction was executed in an agent job,
- No one was writing into original table,
- The instruction was execute with default lock options
- The record count was more than 10 million

Why that record was cloned?

Comment: Are you sure no change were made to the original table (eg. an update to the duplicated record)?

Comment: Are you doing a simple "clone" from single table? Are there joins involved?

Comment: Have you confirmed the current count of the original table doesn't match the cloned?

Comment: someone has added this row otherwise it will be a paranormal activity case, dont blame sql server for that :)

Comment: Please do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [TABLE]; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_cloned;` and check if they match. There's no magic. One thing is that rows can appear in different order, this is why you see the same rows together.

Comment: What is more likely, a bug in SQL 2005 or an omission from your question?

Comment: I don't think this is a bug of sql server (I hope). I write here looking for another explanation.

Next time I'll have to run that job, I'll double-check it.

Answer (score 0):

i recreated your query and executed it through an agent job and it worked fine.
theres nothing wrong with your query.only thing is that  it will give error if you again execute that job as it will try to recreate the table again.

Please use the following query and check the record count.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_CLONED.
```